# Substring to capture one or two digits

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

I'm using Nintex `Build String` action with the inline function of `fn-Substring`. When the input is as follows it works without issue.

```
062015Z062215Zjun16
```

Result `06`

The problem is arises when the date is a single digit it will not be preceded with a `0` so the capture is incorrect

```
62015Z62215Zjun16
```

Result `62`

I'm not sure how to fix the capture.

Comment: What regex are you using now?

Comment: I'm using Nintex which is based on .Net framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe...

```
^(\d{1,2})\d{4}Z
```

Dont know whats constant in your string, but this assumes year always is four digits and followed by a `Z`. If the `Z` isn't constant, maybe `[A-Z]` or something like that will do it...

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bK4xY6/1).